# Rails: Devise - User edit is not generating the HTML I'm expecting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Here's what I have in my users/edit.html/erb

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => user_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>
```

My routes for user:

```
           edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)      users#edit
                user GET    /users/:id(.:format)           users#show
                     PUT    /users/:id(.:format)           users#update
```

method => put, so using the routes info, I am expecting the HTML action to be /users/:id

This being users/edit.html.erb, I am expecting the HTML for from id to be edit_user_id, and class to be edit_user

Here's what I'm actually getting in HTML (using firebug) when the form is displayed:

```
<form id="new_user" class="new_user" method="post" action="/users/user" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

Shouldn't the HTML have been (assuming a user id of 1):

```
<form id="edit_user_1" class="edit_user" method="post" action="/users/1" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

In my routes.rb file, I have:

```
resources :users, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => 'registrations', :confirmations => 'confirmations' }, :path => '', :path_names => { :sign_in => "login", :sign_up => "request_invite" }
```

### Edit - response to Viktor's comment:

I did change the User help to:

```
def resource
  @resource ||= User.find(params[:id])
end
```

So, per the API docs, this should also have picked up /users/:id as an action, so, the HTML should now look like this:

```
<form id="edit_user_1" class="edit_user" method="post" action="/users/1" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

Instead, it is:

```
<form id="edit_user" class="edit_user" method="post" action="/users/user" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

So, when the User controller steps into action, the following code is hit:

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
```

and it thinks that (fron the form's action), that the id I'm passing is the word user, so I'm expecting to get the following error message when I click on update:

Couldn't find User with id=user

and that's exactly what I'm getting as an error. Any additional insight?

## Final Answer:

In users_helper.rb:

```
def resource
  @resource ||= User.find(params[:id])
end
```

and in users/edit.html.erb

resource_name, :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>

Comment: you need to put :url => user_path(resource) not :url => user_path(resource_name) in your form_for, but better leave it out, its all taken care of by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short answer is: it depends on the value of resource in your view.

http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.3/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/apply_form_for_options!
the ids and classes for form are generated by the dom_id and dom_class helpers, the 'action' prefix being 'edit' and not 'new' if and only if:

```
object.respond_to?(:persisted?) && object.persisted?
```

for an activerecord object, this evaluates to true if and only if the object has ever been saved to db.

Comment: The object was saved to the DB when the record was created using the registrations/new.html.erb form. The edit form picks up the right information from the DB and the fields are properly filled. My user helper has the following in it:   def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

Comment: BTW, the link you provided did not work for me. When I replaced v3.2.3 with v3.2.1, it worked

Comment: exactly, if resource is a User.new, it is not persisted. your edit action is supposed to retrieve an existing db record for update, that is why you have id in your params. for edit (and update) your controller action should set @resource = User.find(params[:id]). :)

Comment: Oops, I keep hitting return in the comments section, thinking I will get a new line, instead it posts it. I am going to post this comment as an edit to my original question